# Issue on customizing Homepage in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a [WordPress site for a friend](http://www.dkubeservices.com/) and have a few issues. I am using the Vantage theme by SiteOrigin.

Issues:

1. The area under the banner images section shows an additional 'HOME' link. However, this is not present in my homepage widgets. How can I remove this?
2. All other pages on the website are still under construction, however, they show 'Leave a Comment' section. Please advise on how this can be removed.

Comment: to remove "Leave a comment" section remove or comment this code comments_template()  in page.php from theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Issue#1 'HOME' Linke is the title of the page.If you don't want to show it, remove the **the_title()** tag from  template file.You can also do conditional hide using **is_home()** so that you can  hide page_title just on home page.

For Issue#2  show'Leave a comment', for that you can turn of comment from settings or you can remove the code

```
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
```

from the template file.You can do coditional hide same as above using **is_home()**, **is_page()** etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to take care of issue 1. Thank you. However, I am unable to get rid of the comment box, although it has been unchecked in settings and removing the code you mentioned did not help

Answer (score 0):

to remove "Leave a comment" section remove or comment this code comments_template() in page.php from theme folder.